# Which HRESULT to return when a buffer provided is too small?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, error-handling

I have a function in an `IUnknown`-derived COM interface:

```
HRESULT GetPassword( [in] long bufferLength, [out] WCHAR* buffer );
```

and the contract is that the implementation should check whether the buffer is large enough to store the string being retrieved. If the buffer is large enough the string is copied and `S_OK` is returned, otherwise the function will return an error indication.

However I can't find a suitable `HRESULT` value for that. `E_UNEXPECTED` seems quite dumb and unhelpful. The closest I found is `DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL` but looks like it is for `IDispatch`-derived interfaces only.

Which `HRESULT` should I returned if a buffer provided is too small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return DISP_E_* errors, you are not implementing IDispatch.  E_INVALIDARG is correct here, it is even unambiguous which doesn't happen too often.  Always implement ISupportErrorInfo to generate good error messages, ATL makes it trivial with the Error() method.

Comment: why can't he return DISP_E_*? I mean, I get that it seems inconsistent, but it is more specific than "Invalid Argument", and what is the actual practical risk?

Comment: The programmer won't think the error is caused by his code.  Bad.

Comment: I don't agree. Many COM objects forward inner error messages up the stack to the caller. So even if his interface is not a `IDispatch`, maybe an object that it *uses* is. This is so common, no programmer would actually be confused by it. But I think the whole topic is a bit subjective :)

Comment: You gave the *exact* reason why the programmer thinks it is not his code.

Answer (score 1):

As lame as it sounds, `E_INVALIDARG` is probably your best bet, technically speaking. There are not so many standard `HRESULT`s which are more specific for arguments. There is also `E_POINTER` but it would probably be more confusing.

I would consider using `DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL`. This will be intuitive to callers, and the only risk would be that they don't recognize it because it's not in the standard set of generic HRESULT values. I think that's a pretty small risk though, for a pretty small problem :)

Comment: Well, `E_INVALIDARG` would be perfect in case for example the buffer size passed is negative or zero, but any positive number is okay in general, just in this very case the buffer is not large enough.

Comment: "Invalid" doesn't mean "invalid in general". "Invalid right now in this context" is also just as "invalid". But yea anyway I hate that message because it's so over-used. Personally I would use `DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return an error. You should succeed, fill the buffer with what you can, and return through another parameter how big the buffer needs to be.

If you don't do it this way, how does the caller discover how big a buffer to allocate? You don't seriously want them to call repeatedly, with progressively bigger buffers, until they hit upon a value that suffices? I would hate to have to use such an interface!

Comment: In the spirit of best practices, why go half way way? He should return a `BSTR`.

Comment: @tenfour or a LPWCHAR* that was allocated with the COM allocator, if you have an allergy to `BSTR`. But yes, a grown up string type would be better than these painful C strings.

Comment: You're of course right, but COM interfaces never change once introduced and the implementor has to stick to what already exists.

Comment: @sharptooth I read the Q that the interface was under development, and therefore could be altered. Could be wrong though, it has happened before!!

Comment: Bravo @tenfour! If you still have the control to change the interface, do return a `BSTR` instead. Everybody will be happier.

Answer (score 1):

If you can still do something about it, you should really consider changing the interface to return a `BSTR` instead of a `WCHAR*`. It simplifies a lot of things.

Sometimes you can, sometimes you cannot.

Credit should go to @tenfour for suggesting this. Since you can't post and forward your upvotes to someone else, I'm posting as *community wiki*.