# What's the difference between TYPE_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL and DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL HRESULT values?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, error-handling

Reviewing WinError.h I noticed there're two `HRESULT` values:

```
#define DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80020013L)
#define TYPE_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80028016L)
```

both are claimed to resolve to "buffer too small" text and they both have the same "facility" part and only differ in the "code" part.

What's the difference between these two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL` is intended for general use in `IDispatch` interfaces.

I believe that `TYPE_E_*` errors are intended for type conversion error. `TYPE_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL` appears to be for problems with converting `VARIANT`s or `PROPVARIANT`s. I looked around and found it used in the context of "property bags" (which is a serializable collection); for example, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776532).

In the context of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5039939), `DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL` is a better fit.